# reading nested json with jackson - MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, nested

stucked at accessing nested json. similar stuff:

```
[
{
 key-value,
 key-value
},
{
 key-value,
 key-value
},
{
 key-value,
 key-value
}
]
```

works nicely but when i try:

```
{
  "alfa":{
      "id":"foo",
      "product":{
          "id":"foo1",
          "price":"foo2"
      }
  },
 "beta":{
      "id":"foo",
      "product":{
          "id":"foo1",
          "price":"foo2"
      }
  }
}
```

i get error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<...

i of course did change structure of classes:

```
public class Alphabet{
   private Purchase purchase;
...
```

```
public class Purchase{
   private String id;
   private Product product;
...
```

```
public class Product {
   private String id;
   private String price;
...
```

to read it:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/json/file.json"));
TypeReference<List<Alphabet>> typeReference = new TypeReference<List<Alphabet>>() {};
List<Alphabet> alphabet= mapper.readValue(inputStream, typeReference);
System.out.println(alphabet);
```

whats wrong, please?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the JSON structure you try to read is not a `List<Alphabet>`, but a `Map<String, Purchase>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second json not like list of object. The second json look lik have 2 main objects if so you need class like below.

```
public class Alphabet{
private Purchase purchase;
private Purchase purchase1;
}
```

But it not good practice. Use as first josn like list of objects.